# how do we get the span value

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Below is my html code

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="label-column"> Your Renewal Charges</div>
    <div class="ctrl-column">
        <span data-bind="html: DisplayYourRenewalCharges">
            <span class="CurrencySymbol">USD</span>
                95.00
            </span>
```

I want to scrap the Renewal amount (i.e USD 95.00)

My xpath:

```
String renewalCharge = driver
            .findElement(
                    By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-bind,'html: DisplayYourRenewalCharges')]"))
            .getText();
```

My question is value available in another span class, so the above xpath was not fetching the value

so please suggest to how to re-frame my xpath, to getting that value

Comment: why //div? shouldn't it be //span... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-bind='html: DisplayYourRenewalCharges']")).getText()
```